# Why does enable_if_t in template arguments complains about redefinitions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

I have the following case that works using `std::enable_if` :

```
template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void f() { }

template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void f() { }
```

Now, I saw in cppreference the new syntax, much cleaner in my opinion : `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value>>`

I wanted to port my code :

```
template<typename T,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value>>
void g() { }

template<typename T,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<double, T>::value>>
void g() { }
```

But now GCC (5.2) complains :

```
error: redefinition of 'template<class T, class> void g()'
       void g() { }
```

Why is that so ? What can I do to have the new, more concise syntax in this case if this is possible ?

Comment: Your second code uses default template arguments. They are not part of the function signature, hence you're declaring two function templates with the same signature = redefinition. The corresponding use of `enable_if_t` is literally `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value>* = nullptr`.

Comment: Well, you didn't rewrite your original code exactly. You forgot the `* = nullptr`.

Comment: You can add a dummy template parameter to one of the declarations, like `, typename = void` after `enable_if`

Comment: @dyp: I think you can put your comment as an answer !   
@KerrekSB: no, that's the point of `enable_if_t`   
@PiotrS. : ok

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15427667/ or of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28674543/ or of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8743159/

Comment: I went the `typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value>* = nullptr` route. 4 characters gained, oh well :p

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier You don't need the `typename` in front of `std::enable_if_t`. More characters gained.

Comment: Even more characters gained with `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value, int> = 0` or `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, T>, int> = 0`.

Comment: @Oktalist Just tried but my compiler (gcc 4.9) complains with `*=0` and not with `*=nullptr`.

Comment: That's why I didn't say `*=0`. I supplied `int` as the second argument to `enable_if_t` instead of the default `void`, so `0` is an integer literal, not a null pointer literal.

Comment: I should learn to read.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Let's remove some code.

```
template<
  class T,
  class U/* = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value>*/
 >
void g() { }

template<
  class T,
  class U/* = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<double, T>::value>*/
 >
void g() { }
```

would you be surprised if the compiler rejected the two above templates?

They are both template functions of "type" `template<class,class>void()`.  The fact that the 2nd type argument has a different *default* value matters not.  That would be like expecting two different `print(string, int)` functions with different default `int` values to overload.  ;)

In the first case we have:

```
template<
  typename T,
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type* = nullptr
>
void f() { }

template<
  typename T,
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value>::type* = nullptr
>
void f() { }
```

here we cannot remove the `enable_if` clause.  Updating to `enable_if_t`:

```
template<
  class T,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value, int>* = nullptr
>
void f() { }

template<
  class T,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<double, T>::value, int>* = nullptr
>
void f() { }
```

I also replaced a use of `typename` with `class`.  I suspect your confusion was because `typename` has two meanings -- one as a marker for a kind of `template` argument, and another as a disambiguator for a dependent type.

Here the 2nd argument is a pointer, whose type is dependent on the first.  The compiler cannot determine if these two conflict without first substituting in the type `T` -- and you'll note that they will never actually conflict.

Answer (score 12):

`enable_if_t<B>` is just an alias for `typename enable_if<B>::type`. Let's substitute that in `g` so we can see the real difference between `f` and `g`:

```
template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void f() { }

template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void f() { }

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type>
void g() { }

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value>::type>
void g() { }
```

In the case of `f`, we have two function templates both with template parameters `<typename, X*>`, where the type `X` is *dependent* on the type of the first template *argument*. In the case of `g` we have two function templates with template parameters `<typename, typename>` and it is only the default template argument which is dependent, so C++ considers that they are both declaring the same entity.

Either style can be used with the `enable_if_t` alias:

```
template<typename T,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value>* = nullptr>
void f() { }

template<typename T,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<double, T>::value>* = nullptr>
void f() { }

template<typename T,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value>>
void g() { }

template<typename T,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<double, T>::value>>
void g() { }
```

Comment: If I could accept multiples answers I would have accepted yours as well because it is equally valid! thanks !

Comment: No problem, Yakk's explanation is slightly better.

Answer (score 4):

For a function return type, you're looking for the following:

```
template<typename T> std::enable_if_t< conditional, instantiation result > foo();
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

// when T is "int", replace with 'void foo()'   
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value, void> foo() {
    std::cout << "foo int\n";
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<float, T>::value, void> foo() {
    std::cout << "foo float\n";
}

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    foo<float>();
}
```

http://ideone.com/TB36gH

see also

http://ideone.com/EfLkQy

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late to the thread but since the idea behind the question was to have a cleaner syntax, I would like to mention another approach using function template specialization. It is not as general purpose as using `enable_if` but works well if all we want are different instantiations of `f` for different types.

```
template <typename T>
void f() = delete;

template <>
void f<int>() { }

template <>
void f<double>() { }
```

If the template is instantiated for any type besides `int` and `double` you get the following error message

```
<source>:18:5: error: call to deleted function 'foo'
   18 |     foo<char>();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:4:6: note: candidate function [with T = char] has been explicitly deleted
    4 | void foo() = delete;
      |      ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score -7):

You're missing a "::type" ..

```
 template<typename T,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type>
    void g() { }

    template<typename T,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<double, T>::value>::type>
    void g() { }
```

Comment: `std::enable_if_t` is an alias template of a nested `::type` definition of `std::enable_if`