# Type trait dependent specialization of template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a simple templated function, defined in a library I am using

```
template<class T>
T create(std::vector<char>& data)
{ 
    T newValue{}; 
    /* Do something with data */
    return newValue;
}
```

and I want to specialize this function in case T implements a specific interface

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Interface, T>::value, T> create( std::vector<char>& data)
{ 
    T newValue{};
    newValue.InterfaceFunction(data);
    return newValue;
}
```

but I cannot make this work, the function I have specialized is not used. How can I achieve making a specialization of an already defined template function?

Comment: shouldn't it be just `template<>` in the specialization?

Comment: @Oneiros, I need the definition of class T in the predicate

Comment: I think this is the reason why it is not working, you are not technically specializing the first function if you still use the T class... the compiler sees the second one as a totally different function

Comment: Sorry, the example was bad, I have rewritten it. Is it still not technically possible?

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500426/why-does-enable-if-t-in-template-arguments-complains-about-redefinitions) help?

Comment: @Oneiros I have tried that way, but then it becomes ambigous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not template specialization but templates overloading, and function templates can't be partial specialized. The problem is that when you specify a type deriving from `Interface` both the function templates are exact match, which leads to ambiguity.

You can apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<Interface, T>::value, T> create(std::vector<char>& data)
{ 
    T newValue{}; 
    /* Do something with data */
    return newValue;
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Interface, T>::value, T> create( std::vector<char>& data)
{ 
    T newValue{};
    newValue.InterfaceFunction(data);
    return newValue;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jJ12NrfPijHrfM14)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know it can be done this way, IF i was allowed to change the original definition, but I am not.

Comment: @thorsan I added some explanation about why the original definition doesn't work.

Comment: @thorsan: If possible, you may still create `my_create` which calls unmodifiable `create` for non interface, else the specialized function.

Comment: @Jarod42, yes, that is what I ended up doing, creating a wrapper function with SFINAE, as in the above answer, selecting the right one.